# S is nowhere dense in M if and only if its closure has empty interior

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can some one please give a full explanation on this quistion? I really can't understand the answer.
Show that S a subset of M is some where dense in M if and only if int(cl(S)) is not empty.

Comment: A set $A$ is called nowhere dense, if there is no neighbourhood $U$ in which it is dense, ie if the closure $\bar A$ does not contain any set that contains an open set. This is equivalent to $\bar A$ having empty interior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $S$ is somewhere dense in $M$. This means by definition that there is some non-empty open set $O$ of $M$ such that $S \cap O$ is dense in $O$.

Now take $x \in O$, and let $U_x$ be any open neighbourhood of $x$. Then $O \cap U_x$ is also an open neighbourhood of $x$ and is an open subset of $O$ as well, and so intersects $S \cap O$, say in $y \in (O \cap U_x) \cap (S \cap O)$. This $y \in S \cap U_x$ in particular so as $U_x$ is arbitrary, $x \in \overline{S}$.

This shows that $O \subseteq \overline{S}$, and so $\operatorname{Int}(\overline{S}) \neq \emptyset$ as witnessed by the non-empty set $O$.

Now suppose $O = \operatorname{Int}(\overline{S}) (\subseteq \overline{S})$ is non-empty. Then $O \cap S$ is dense in $O$: let $x \in O$, and $U_x$ be any open neighbourhood of $x$. Then $U_x \cap O$ contains $x$ and so $x \in \overline{S}$, so $U_x \cap (O \cap S) \neq \emptyset$. As $U_x$ was arbitrary, $O \cap S$ is dense in $O$ as claimed.